# how to replace with sed when source contains $

Tags: sed, escaping, echo

I have a file that contains:

```
$conf['minified_version'] = 100;
```

I want to increment that 100 with sed, so I have this:

```
sed -r 's/(.*minified_version.*)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1$((\2+1))\3"/ge'
```

The problem is that this strips the `$conf` from the original, along with any indentation spacing. What I have been able to figure out is that it's because it's trying to run:

```
echo "    $conf['minified_version'] = $((100+1));"
```

so of course it's trying to replace the `$conf` with a variable which has no value.

Comment: The problem here has nothing to do with the `$` in the source -- you're already writing your regex in such a way as to not include any literal `$`, so you're avoiding the obvious gotcha of putting a line-end anchor at the beginning of your expression (a gotcha you could also avoid by starting with `^[$]`). Rather, it has everything to do with trying to have `sed` evaluate a shell command in generating the replacement content, which it doesn't support and never did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an awk version:

```
$ awk '/minified_version/{$3+=1} 1' file
$conf['minified_version'] = 101
```

This looks for lines that contain `minified_version`.  Anytime such a line is found the third field, `$3`, is incremented by.

Comment: thanks! this is a pretty clean solution - it was omitting the semicolon at the end of the line, but an easy fix for that was just to put a space between the number and the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

My suggested approach to this would be to have a file on-disk that contained **nothing but** the minified_version number. Then, incrementing that number would be as simple as:

```
minified_version=$(< minified_version)
printf '%s\n' "$(( minified_version + 1 ))" >minified_version
```

...and you could just put a sigil in your source file where that needs to be replaced. Let's say you have a file named `foo.conf.in` that contains:

```
$conf['minified_version'] = @MINIFIED_VERSION@
```

...then you could simply run, in your build process:

```
sed -e "s/@MINIFIED_VERSION@/$(<minified_version)/g" <foo.conf.in >foo.conf
```

This has the advantage that you never have code changing `foo.conf.in`, so you don't need to worry about bugs overwriting the file's contents. It also means that if you're checking your files into source control, so long as you only check in `foo.conf.in` and not `foo.conf` you avoid potential merge conflicts due to context near the version number changing.

---

Now, if you *did* want to do the native operation in-place, here's a somewhat overdesigned approach written in pure native bash (reading from `infile` and writing to `outfile`; just rename `outfile` back over `infile` when successful to make this an in-place replacement):

```
target='$conf['"'"'minified_version'"'"'] = '
suffix=';'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = "$target"* ]]; then
    value=${line##*=}
    value=${value%$suffix}
    new_value=$(( value + 1 ))
    printf '%s\n' "${target}${new_value}${suffix}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done <infile >outfile
```